# How to convert a JSON JString value to an ordinary String in Lift?

Tags: string, json, scala, lift, lift-json

Having a `jString : JString` value holding an `"abc"` string inside I get `"JString(abc)" : String` if I call `jString.toString`. How do I get `"abc" : String` instead?

Comment: I've found the solution to use `jString.values : String` but I feel uncertain if it's correct - why is it called `values` (not a `value`) if there's just a `String`?

Answer (score 19):

To extract a value from JValue you can use any method described here: [What is the most straightforward way to parse JSON in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169153/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-parse-json-in-scala/4169292#4169292)

For instance:

```
json.extract[String]
```

You can use 'render' function to convert any JValue to printable format. Then either 'pretty' or 'compact' will convert that to a String.

```
compact(render(json))
```

or

```
pretty(render(json))
```

Comment: I don't want to render JSON. I want the opposite - to extract a string value of a property of an object serialized in JSON and I've already isolated that only field into a separate JString, containing nothing but the value I need.

Answer (score 7):

```
val jstring=JString("abc")
implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats 
System.out.println(jstring.extract[String])
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe the best way is to use match:

```
val x = ... (whatever, maybe it's a JString)

x match {
  case JString(s) => do something with s
  case _          => oops, something went wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a while ago, but I wanted a simple one-line helper that would get my string for me in the context of an expression, so I wrote this little thing inside of an object called Get:

```
  object Get {
    def string(value: JValue): String = {                                                                                                               
      val JString(result) = value                                                                                            
      result                                                                                                                              
    }
  ...
  }
```

This way I can just do, e.g., val myString = Get.string(jsonStringValue)